# Other packages available from my package's tab-completion

Tags: python, package, python-import, pypi, tab-completion

When I import a Python 3 package I created, the tab-completion for the package includes some packages that are imported by my package from other packages like `pandas`.

The package has this basic structure:

```
foo/
    foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    baz.py
    qux.py
    setup.py
```

My `__init__.py` contains

```
from .bar import *
from .baz import *
from .qux import *
```

The problem is that `baz.py` looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

def f1(data):
    # do something with pandas (pd)

def f2(data):
    # do something different with pandas (pd)
```

Thus, when I `import foo`, I get tab-completion options like `foo.pd`, which is not really a valid anything. For all `foo.X` I want `X` to be a function or class defined by me, not imported from another package.

What is the best way around this? Should I add `import pandas as pd` to `__init__.py`? I know I could `import pandas as pd` inside of every single function, but that seems like overkill for anything more than a trivial example like this one.

Is it just a problem with Jupyter's tab-completion?

Comment: "Thus, when I `import foo`, I get tab-completion options like `foo.pd`, which is not really a valid anything." Sure it is. Try it out! You should have access to all of `pandas` via `foo.pd`. Anyway, there's a way to avoid this. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Set [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) in your `__init__.py` to define what should be exposed when you `import *` from your module:

> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import) statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when `from package import *` is encountered. It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released.

For example:

```
__all__ = ["stuff", "you", "want", "to", "expose"]
```

Alternatively, you can `import pandas as _pd` since [names starting with `_` won't be imported by default](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't exactly lead to the behavior I am looking for. If I do `from foo import *`, I'd have to call `baz.f1(data)` instead of just `foo.f1()`.